# How can i change collapsed navbar content in Bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i would be appriciate if someone can help to get answer this question:
i have some elemets in my HTML page and i want to add them automatically to collapsed navbar (in this tag :

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
   <ul>
     <li>---here---</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

) when display's width is changed
note:these elements are not in navbar

Comment: Append the class `visible-xs` to the `<li>`.

Answer (score 0):

first of all thanks @Airbrean ,
yes your right ,we can add some data to our navbar with class which you mentioned but i think it's not optimised and make **Redundancy** in our Html codes.
anyway this is only way which i found to do that I asked till now :

`<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="visible-xs">
    ----Some items Here--------
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>`